# Changing process name when running Python as daemon

Tags: python, daemon, upstart, start-stop-daemon

I found this excellent website which gives an [example upstart script for running Python scripts as daemons](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/). My question is, can I change the name it reports as when I type ps -e?

I was thinking start-stop-daemon might have an option to do that but I haven't found it.

Comment: What operating system are you running? What version of Python?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

In pure python, there's no easy way to do it.

The [setproctitle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setproctitle/) package, however, could prove useful. It allows a python process to set its process name. It's a C extension that has support for a number of operating systems, and supports both Python 2 and 3. It does appear that it may be unmaintained now, but it is still working well for me.